# control ggplot2 plot size (not including axis labels)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following 2 bar plots. They were saved as exactly the same size, but the actual sizes of the bars are quite different, because in the second plot the y axis has more digits, so the actual plotting area is smaller. I was wondering if there is a way to specify only the size of the plotting area (not including the axis texts), and thus make sure the sizes of the bars are consistent across these plots.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Jan", "Feb"),
                 y = c(1, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  ggsave("~/test/p1.png", width = 2, height = 2)

df$y <- 10000 * df$y
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  ggsave("~/test/p2.png", width = 2, height = 2)
```

p1:

[image]

p2:

[image]

Comment: If you're combining plots, the `patchwork` package does this for you. I suppose a hacky approach to make separate plots with align axes could be to make a combined plot using patchwork and then `magick` or something to crop that into separate files...

Comment: The accepted solution using cowplot here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-control-the-size-of-the-panel-in-a-ggplot-so-they-are-consistent/14377/5 will align plots, but then allow you to plot them separately